# Flannel fails in kubernetes cluster due to failure of subnet manager

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, kubectl, flannel

I am running `etcd`, `kube-apiserver`, `kube-scheduler`, and `kube-controllermanager` on a master node as well as `kubelet` and `kube-proxy` on a minion node as follows (all kube binaries are from kubernetes 1.7.4):

```
# [master node]
./etcd
./kube-apiserver --logtostderr=true --etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:2379 --service-cluster-ip-range=10.10.10.0/24 --insecure-port 8080 --secure-port=0 --allow-privileged=true --insecure-bind-address 0.0.0.0
./kube-scheduler --address=0.0.0.0 --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080
./kube-controller-manager --address=0.0.0.0 --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080

# [minion node]
./kubelet --logtostderr=true --address=0.0.0.0 --api_servers=http://$MASTER_IP:8080 --allow-privileged=true
./kube-proxy --master=http://$MASTER_IP:8080
```

After this, if I execute `kubectl get all --all-namespaces` and `kubectl get nodes`, I get

```
NAMESPACE   NAME             CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
default     svc/kubernetes   10.10.10.1   <none>        443/TCP   27m

NAME       STATUS    AGE       VERSION
minion-1   Ready     27m       v1.7.4+793658f2d7ca7
```

Then, I apply flannel as follows:

```
kubectl apply -f kube-flannel-rbac.yml -f kube-flannel.yml
```

Now, I see a pod is created, but with error:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                    READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-p8tcb   1/2       CrashLoopBackOff   4          2m
```

When I check the logs inside the failed container in the minion node, I see the following error:

```
Failed to create SubnetManager: unable to initialize inclusterconfig: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory
```

My question is: how to resolve this? Is this a SSL issue? What step am I missing in setting up my cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is your flannel yaml file has something wrong,
you can try this to install your flannel,
check the old ip link

`ip link`

if it show flannel,please delete it

`ip link delete flannel.1`

and install , its default pod network cdir is 10.244.0.0/16

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/v0.9.0/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass **--etcd-prefix=/your/prefix** and **--etcd-endpoints=address** to flanneld instead of **--kube-subnet-mgr** so flannel get *net-conf* from etcd server and not from api server.

Keep in mind that you must to push  net-conf to etcd server.

**UPDATE**

The problem (`/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory`) can appear when execute apiserver without **--admission-control=...,ServiceAccount,...** or if kubelet is inside a container (eg: hypercube) and this last was my case. If you want execute k8s components inside a container you need to pass 'shared' option to kubelet volume

> /var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw,shared

Furthermore enable same option to docker in docker.service

> MountFlags=shared

Now the question is: is there a security hole with shared mount?